# Density of $\{ v \in C^0[0,1]: v(0)=0\}$ in $C^0[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, approximation, pointwise-convergence

Let $V = \{ v \in C^0[0,1]: v(0)=0\}$. I need to show this set is dense in $C^0[0,1]$ with respect to the $L^2$ norm.

I was thinking to select a sequence of functions $\{ f_n \} \in V$ such that $f_n(0)=0$ so they're in $V$ and as $n$ increase I am always closer to $f(0)$, being $f$ the function I want to approximate.

I came up with $f_n(x)= $ \begin{cases} f(\frac{1}{n})x, \qquad x \in I_n \\f(x) \qquad x \not \in I_n ​\end{cases}

---

Okay, here's what I did: I need to show that $$||f_n -f||_{L^2(0,1)} \rightarrow 0$$
As the sequence and the original function $f$ agree except on $I_n$, I need to compute that difference on $I_n$ only.

Then I have:

$$\int_0^{1/n}(f(\frac{1}{n})x - f(x))^2dx =_\underbrace{nx = t} \int_0^1 \Bigl(f\bigl(\frac{1}{n}\bigr) \frac{t}{n} - f\bigl(\frac{t}{n} \bigr) \Bigr)^2 \frac{dt}{n} $$ Taking the limit, that integral goes to $0$. Is this correct?

Comment: What's the norm/metric here? It cannot be dense for the uniform norm because the pointwise limit at $0$ will always be $0$.

Comment: The exercise was about showing that $V$ was dense in $L^2$ by showing that $V$ is dense in $C^0$ and then using the density of continuous functions in $L^p$. So I should use the $L^2$ norm? @nejimban

Comment: Yes, of course! It won't work for the infinite norm.

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to fix it right now :-) @nejimban

Comment: @nejimban I edited my post, is my solution correct?

Comment: The $f_n$ you took is a good candidate. You should perhaps emphasize that it is continuous (to be in $V$), and also explain a bit more why that last integral goes to $0$.

Comment: @nejimban Both terms in the integral go to $0$, and are multiplied by things like $f(t/n)$, which is bounded. Is this sufficient?

Comment: @nejimban I edited one last time. there were some typos. I'd say that since $f(0)$ is bounded then that limit is $0$

Comment: Kind of. Passing to the limit under the integral requires some care. But I guess you can bound the integral by $2\|f\|_\infty^2/n^2+2\|f\|_2^2/n$, so that is fine.

Comment: @nejimban I'm sorry, one last thing: am I right if I say that my $f_n$ are not continuous? Taking the limit from both sides to $\frac{1}{n}$ gives two different values, right

Comment: Indeed, I read too quickly. It should be $nxf(x)$ for $x\in I_n$, as in @Cryptokyo's answer. Then $\|f_n-f\|_2^2=O(\frac1n)$.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so you have essentially done it with a few adjustments needed! If you define

$$g_n(x):= \begin{cases} nxf(x), &x \in I_{n} \\ 
f(x), & x\not\in I_{n}\end{cases}$$

we have $g_{n}(0)=0$ and $g_{n}$ is continuous as $\lim_{x\uparrow\frac{1}{n}}g_{n}(x) = \lim_{x\uparrow\frac{1}{n}}nxf(x)=f(\frac{1}{n})$ and $\lim_{x\downarrow\frac{1}{n}}g_{n}(x) = \lim_{x\downarrow\frac{1}{n}}f(x)=f(\frac{1}{n})$ by the continuity of $f$.

Moreover, one has that $$\begin{split}\lVert f-g_{n}\rVert_{L^{2}} & = \int_{(0,1)}(f(x)-g_{n}(x))^{2}dx \\ & =\int_{(0,\frac{1}{n})}(f(x))^{2}(1-nx)^{2}dx \\ & \leq \sup_{(0,1)}|f|^{2}\int_{(0,\frac{1}{n})}1-2nx+n^{2}x^{2} dx \\
& = \frac{1}{3n}\sup_{(0,1)}|f|^{2} \end{split}$$ Finally we have that $\sup_{(0,1)}|f|^{2} < \infty$ as $f$ is defined on a compact set and is thus bounded. Since $n$ was arbitrary we are done.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is wrong in my edit? @Cryptokyo

Comment: @bobinthebox I'm sorry I'm not quite sure what you are meaning here?

Comment: If you look at my question, I tried to prove that my sequence $f_n$ converges to $f$... is my proof correct?

Comment: Your $f_{n}$ are not continuous since you have $\lim_{x\uparrow \frac{1}{n}} f_{n}(x) = \lim_{x\uparrow \frac{1}{n}} xf(\frac{x}{n}) = \frac{1}{n}f(\frac{1}{n^{2}})$ but $\lim_{x\downarrow \frac{1}{n}} f_{n}(x) = f(\frac{1}{n})$. So your proof does not follow.

Comment: There was a typo, the right one is $x f(\frac{1}{n})$. That will work

Comment: But even then you still have that $\lim_{x\uparrow \frac{1}{n}}f_{n}(x)\lim_{x\uparrow \frac{1}{n}} xf(\frac{1}{n}) = \frac{1}{n}f(\frac{1}{n}) \neq f(\frac{1}{n}) = \lim_{x\downarrow \frac{1}{n}}f_{n}(x)$ and your $f_{n}$ are not continuous. My $g_{n}$ definition recovers this continuity.

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry